# Cannot retrieve data in Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a Flex application and I want to get some data from an XML file. In my PC, I am getting  the data using the HTTPService and when I try from other PC in the same network, I am getting a permission error. I have given the URL property of HTTPService as myIPAddress/data.xml

I am getting the following error

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Security error accessing url" faultCode="Channel.Security.Error" faultDetail="Destination: DefaultHTTP"]
```

I have searched abou this and found that a crossdomainpolicy.xml file need to be placed in web root directory to give permission to access the data.

Here is the content of my crossdomainpolicy.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Still my problem is not resolved. Can anybody help me on this?

Regards

Dijo

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you use subdomains for making the calls ? 
   the the corssdomain.xml should be in the subdomain root.
2. Can you give a sample of the HTTPService url you are setting.
3. Are you using:

Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://yourdomain/crossdomain.xml");

Comment: Hi Adrian. I m currently doing it in my localhost and accessing it from other PC. Can you please explain Where I need to use the 3rd point.

Comment: On your main application mxml/as class listen for creationComplete event and add this 2 lines in the handler. You need to set this in dere or any other time point but before making any server request.